# Measuring DHCP time in Android

Tags: java, android

For my thesis I need to measure how long in each stage it takes to connect to a WiFi AP.

I can easily measure everything using SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I can measure the time it takes to get the DHCP information.

I just really need to know with a certain precision when the android device gets a new IP. I've tried using CONNECTIVITY_ACTION and inside the BroadcastReceiver checking the IP address, but it's off by at least 1 second, so not too precise.

One more thing if it's relevant: The AP on which I will do the tests won't have internet connection.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem the following way:

Created a filter with WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION

And when there is a new event, I check it the following way:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)){
  elapseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
  WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
  int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
  if (ipAddress != 0 && !wifiConnected) {
    wifiConnected = true;
    wifiTimeLog = wifiTimeLog + elapseTime + "," + "DHCP Done" + "\n";
    state.setText(wifiTimeLog);
 }
```

wifiConnected is a boolean that is set to false before the test. There were some other triggers happening after getting the IP.